# How can I make my apps only available from nginx and not from the direct ports on ubuntu?

Tags: docker

I have a VPS with ubuntu and I want to host my apps on it.
I run my apps with docker and it is working - my apps run on localhost with the port I set them to using the docker-compose file.
The thing is, that I can also access those apps through the server's ip (by entring the port number of the app) even though I didn't configure it on nginx. So I can go to `example.com:3000` for example, and see my node app even if I didn't configure nginx to host it.

I want my apps to only be accessible through nginx, and only if configure them to. Is there a way to do it? I tried activating the firewall using `ufw enable`, but it doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: Bind the ports to localhost instead of all interfaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly block access to a port forwarded docker container?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080075/how-to-correctly-block-access-to-a-port-forwarded-docker-container)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks! That was it, it works now!